# How to Sync Notes El Capitan to iOS 9 via IMAP

Tags: notes.app, macos, imap, ios

Yes, I know Apple says this will no longer work. But it continues to work just fine on iOS 9 devices. Both iPad and iPhone iOS 9 devices continue to sync via my IMAP account. I enter or modify a note on iPad and I see the change on iPhone immediately, and vice versa. And my web mail client see the Notes folder with the updates. All sub-folders are visible in iPhone and iPad and in the web mail client...but not on Mac OS X.

How can I fix my Mac Notes configuration to reenable syncing via IMAP? I don't need the new features of Notes on El Capitan... I need basic synchronization of simple notes between all devices. I can't use iCloud or any other for-profit web service, I need to sync through a specific IMAP server for compliance reasons.

I've tried restoring the old Notes app, but Apple disallows this during the Time Machine restore function.

Thanks

Comment: I restored the ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.notes folder from before the El Capitan upgrade. All IMAP notes were restored, and the system quickly synched back to current. New notes posted to any of the subfolders and changes made to existing notes are now synched correctly. Changes made to iPad or iPhone notes are reflected immediately on the Mac Notes. But changes made on Mac Notes do not propagate as quickly. The iPad or iPhone notes need to be manually refreshed to see the updates. --@M.Abel

Comment: I noticed that my old iPhone 3S (I still use it!) stopped synching with El Capitan. The captain doesn't seem to deal with oldies any more >.-( (angry one-eyed pirate)

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else stumbling over this because Notes.app stopped syncing IMAP based notes in El Capitan 10.11.3, the solution which worked for me is the following:

Firstly, check that the **IMAP Path Prefix** is correct for the account. This can be done in *System Preferences / Internet Accounts / (select your account) / Advanced* or in *Mail.app / Preferences / Accounts / (select your IMAP account) / Advanced*. In my case, this was set correctly to `INBOX`, but sometimes requires different values, or no value at all.

Secondly, the [solution](http://rene.margar.fr/2015/10/refaire-fonctionner-notes-avec-imap-sous-osx-el-capitan/) given above by @rene actually works, but it's in French, so here's a step-by-step approach that worked for me.

1. Open Terminal.app to get a command prompt
2. Change directory to the following folder:

`bash> cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/`

3. Make a backup the file NotesV6.storedata so that you can restore it in case something goes wrong

`bash> cp NotesV6.storedata NotesV6.storedata.old`

4. Open `NotesV6.storedata` with sqlite3

`bash> sqlite3 NotesV6.storedata`

5. A new sqlite prompt will appear - you can always exit by pressing `CTRL-D`

`sqlite>`

6. (Optional) You can examine the table that we need to fix by entering the followoing command

`sqlite> .schema ZACCOUNT`

7. The `ZACCOUNT` table contains all accounts which Notes.app is accessing. However, in my case, the IMAP based account entry was missing information about username (field `ZUSERNAME`), hostname (field `ZHOSTNAME`) and path prefix (field `ZSERVERPATHPREFIX`). This is the information we need to update.
8. You can dump the whole table by invoking

`sqlite> select * from ZACCOUNT`

but it's probably easier to select a few relevant fields and identify the `Z_PK` id of your account

`sqlite> select Z_PK,ZFULLNAME,ZPARENTACACCOUNTIDENTIFIER,ZUSERNAME, ZHOSTNAME, ZSERVERPATHPREFIX from ZACCOUNT;`

This produced the following output for me:

```
1||
4|Exchange|EF792FA7-AAAA-CCCC-5678-123456789012|||
5|IMAPaccount|187229D1-BBBB-DDDD-1234-098765431287|||
```

As you can see by the field divider lines (`|`) at the end of the last line, fields for username, hostname, and prefix are empty for the IMAP account (`Z_PK` id 5) which is what needs to be corrected.

9. Update the table entry by invoking:

`update ZACCOUNT set ZUSERNAME='email@example.com', ZHOSTNAME='imap.hostname.com',ZSERVERPATHPREFIX='INBOX.' where Z_PK=5;`

You will of course need to set the correct field values and also adjust the `Z_PK` id with the correct reference, which you identified above.

10. As soon as I'd updated the table, Notes.app started magically syncing the notes from my IMAP based accounts.

Answer (score -2):

When using notes.app in El Capitan, I've noticed that the account settings are lost in the Notes config file. It's a sqlite3 file, I've described what to do in my blog: [Refaire fonctionner Notes avec IMAP sous OSX El Capitan](http://rene.margar.fr/2015/10/refaire-fonctionner-notes-avec-imap-sous-osx-el-capitan/). It's in french you may use google translate if you can't read french.

It says that you need to open with sqlite3 file ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV6.storedata
and execute some SQL statements with your imap settings (account, server, prefix)

Comment: Since this is an english q&a site please add all necessary steps in english instead of posting an almost link-only answer.