# Notes won't sync via IMAP in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, notes.app, imap

Recently I updated my MacBook from Mavericks to Sierra and everything is going well… except the sync of my notes. I don't want to use iCloud sync because I don't want my notes on a foreign server. Yes, I am aware, that the new features are not supported by IMAP but I don't use them. I just use unformatted text.

What I have tried so far:

- disabling the account, reboot, an re-enabling it -> didn't work
- deleting  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes -> didn't work
- following the description here: [How to Sync Notes El Capitan to iOS 9 via IMAP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208719/how-to-sync-notes-el-capitan-to-ios-9-via-imap) -> didn't work
- searching the internet -> no further hints

How can I get this sync back to work?

Comment: Restoring the NotesV2.storedata file from a Time Machine backup "restores" the notes. But the sync is still not working. I'm not sure whether the old file put a copy of my notes into the Notes.app or forced a single synchronisation.

Answer (score 2):

I was quite desperate with this issue as well after a clean install of High Sierra, here is how you setup Notes.app to find the correct imap folder:

**System Preferences > Internet Accounts > [your account] > Advanced...**

Check if your **Path Prefix** is set correct. In my case this was blank which worked fine for Mail.app but had to be set to `INBOX` to work for Notes.app

I hope this helps somebody.