# Anyone successfully syncing IMAP Notes with High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, notes.app, imap

I regularly use the Notes app with our corporate IMAP server to share notes between my devices. (Corporate policy forbids us from using iCloud or any other 3rd party service.)

This used to work fine, but since I've updated one of my two laptops to High Sierra (the other is still on Sierra), syncing no longer works as expected. Specifically:

- If I create a note on either laptop, it never appears on the other laptop or my iPad (which is still running iOS 10).
- If I create a note on my iPad, it appears only on the Sierra laptop, and changes I make are synced back to the iPad.

Any ideas? Could I expect it to work again if I upgraded the other laptop to High Sierra as well?

Comment: I just answered a possible duplicate question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265579/notes-wont-sync-via-imap-in-macos-sierra

Comment: Thanks. Without yet having tried your suggestion, it now seems to have become even more erratic. About 20% of my notes have made it from the Sierra laptop to the High Sierra one over the course of a couple of months, but it doesn't seem to want to do any more than that...